# WSO2 DataService (DataSource) Return Custom Error Message

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server

How to return **Custom Error Response** when using ***WSO2 EI(6.5.0)*** DataService

**I am getting this error when validation input values :**

```
{
    "Fault": {
        "faultcode": "axis2ns16:VALIDATION_ERROR",
        "faultstring": "DS Code: VALIDATION_ERROR\nNested Exception:-\njavax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Code: VALIDATION_ERROR\nSource Data Service:-\nName: MWGetBranchCodes\nLocation: \\MWGetBranchCodes.dbs\nDescription: N/A\nDefault Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice\nCurrent Request Name: _post_getbankcodes\nCurrent Params: {SOURCE=source, REQUESTER=bond, FUNCTION=function, SECURITYCODE=1FE550839D5DD7933032340DA85F614}\nNested Exception:-\nSecuritycode and Function are not matched : \nField Name: SECURITYCODE\nField Value: 1FE550839D5DD7933032340DA85F614\n\n",
        "detail": ""
    }
}
```

**i want this  :**

```
{
    "Error": {
        "ErrorCode": "0", 0-failed/ 1-success
        "ErrorMessage": "VALIDATION_ERROR : Securitycode is NULL",
        "detail": " \nField Name: SECURITYCODE\nField Value: null\n\n"
    }
}
```

Help me please Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for that behaviour you need to create custom validators, check this post: 
http://mycodeideas.blogspot.com/2016/07/custom-validators-with-wso2-dss.html

Comment: but it throws Validationexception ? How to handle this using proxy service
in fault Sequence,
if wso2 EI DS return fault exception, so then Wso2 proxy service which class this DS returns error json message?